# if statement inside an Array?

Tags: php

I'm having issues with trying to put values gotten from a SQL table into an array.

I can't paste the exact code but here it is with the names substituted :

```
$fruit_table = array (
    if ($result_fruits->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row2 = $result_fruits->fetch_assoc()) {
            $row2['fruit_id'] . "=>" . $row2['fruit_name'] . ","
        } 
    }
);
```

I need this in order to later on assign a name to a value which will be in an id form.

```
<td>" . $fruits_table[$row['input_fruit']] . "</td>
```

Comment: What are your exact issues?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea I've got a page table that gets data from one DB table which only contains the "fruit_id" but I am aiming to display the fruit_name" so I need to get that from another DB table as above and I am trying add those results from the second query to an array so in the page table I can run each id off of the array and get the name that corresponds to each id.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is certainly not the way to go.. Try it like this

```
$fruit_table = array();
while($row2 = $result_fruits->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fruit_table[$row2['fruit_id']] = $row2['fruit_name'];
}
```